# What is the regulatory process of being able to produce and sell an alcoholic drink in South Africa commercially?

Tags: wine, laws, mead

We have started producing small batches of a unique honey mead that is doing well in small to large stall type markets. What are the steps that need to be followed in order to get a license to continue to produce and distribute an alcoholic beverage in South Africa?

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search for "alcohol manufacturing south africa" turns up a lot of helpful results...

Essentially, you need to apply for a [macro manufacturing and/or distribution liquor license](https://liquorlicense.co.za/distribution-liquor-license/). In order to do so, you will need to register with the [National Liquor Authority (NLA) of South Africa](https://thenla.thedti.gov.za/).

The information you need to provide and requirements you need to meet include, but are not limited to: *company information, financial interest in the liquor industry, obtaining a "B-BEE" Certificate (Broad-Based Black Economic Empowerment Codes of Good Practice,) projected annual turnover, and a registration fee*.

Required documents include:

> Applications should be accompanied by:
>
> - A business zoning certificate for industrial purposes or a consent    letter from the relevant municipality;
> - A comprehensive written representation in support of the application;
> - Any determination, consent approval or authority required by the Act;
> - Valid proof that the prescribed application fee has been deposited in    the bank account of the dti;
> - A valid certified copy of ID or passport of the applicant;
> - Trading business permit if the applicant is a foreigner;
> - A South African Police Services (SAPS) police clearance certificate    not older than three months from the date of issue;
> - If the applicant is a juristic person, valid copies of registration    issued by the Companies and Intellectual Property    Commission   (CIPC) or any other relevant registration authority    indicating the financial interest of all members, shareholders,    partners or   beneficiaries as the case may be;
> - A valid tax clearance certificate if the applicant is a juristic    person issued by the South African Revenue Services (SARS) within 12 months from the date of application;
> - Verification certificate issued in terms of the B-BBEE Act.

Considering that the sales and distribution ban in South Africa was recently lifted, I'd say it's a good time to get registered, if you have not already. ;)